# Markov chain definition: should the conditional probability also hold if $P(X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = 0$? Is $S$ a set of real numbers?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

**Definition of Markov Chain (as it is stated in my textbook):**

Let $S$ be a set of states and $\mathbb P = \{p_{i,j}\}$, $i,j \in S$ a transistion matrix . Then the sequence of RV's $(X_{n})_{n \ge 0}$ is a Markov chain, if $P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = p_{i_n, i_{n+1}}$ for $n \ge 0$ and $i_{n+1}, \ldots, i_0 \in S$.

**Question:**

Should $P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = p_{i_n, i_{n+1}}$ also hold if $i_{n+1}, \ldots, i_0 \in S$ are chosen such that $P(X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = 0$ which mean $$P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = \frac {P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1},X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)} {P(X_{n} = i_{n}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)}$$
is undefined ? Is it implicit in the definition that such cases should be ignored, since they cannot occur ?

Also, is it implicit in the definition that $S$ is a countable or countable infinite set of real numbers or could the set be arbitrary ?

Comment: Please grab a textbook, this is entirely standard stuff.

Comment: Yes, but it is not stated explicitly.

Comment: Which textbook(s) are you using?

Comment: Saeed Ghahramani Fundamentals of Probability, with Stochastic Processes, Charles M. Grinstead, J. Laurie Snell Introduction to Probability

Comment: And neither of these explains what to do when the probability is zero?

Comment: If you know a good book that does please give me the title.

Comment: True, Ghahramani defines without being very cautious a Markov chain as you do, without explaining what happens in the 0/0 cases. Grinstead and Snell (Chapter 11) take the safer, more sound mathematically, approach of *defining* a Markov chain by specifying every $P(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)$ as the product you know, *then* deducing *as a property* that, when $P(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)\ne0$, the conditioning identity in your post holds. So G&S is allright. Norris *Markov chains* is a standard reference.

Comment: Thank you very much @Did. What exactly do you mean by "as the product you know" ?

Comment: $P(X_0=x_0)p_{x_0x_1}p_{x_1x_2}\cdots p_{x_{n-1}x_n}$. What else?

Comment: So instead of the definition in Ghahramani (using conditional), we should define a Markov chain by $$P(X_0 =x_0, X_1 = x_1, \ldots, X_n = x_n) = P(X_0 = x_0)p_{x_0x_1} \dots p_{x_{n-1}x_n}$$ and then the conditional property will follow as a consequence ? Could we not just consider that if $P(X_0 =x_0, X_1 = x_1, \ldots, X_n = x_n) = 0$ then the event cannot happen, so in this case undefined, and it is then implicit that the conditional property should only hold for elements in $S$ with probability not equal to $0$ (Ghahramani definition) ?

Comment: This seems to be paraphrasing what I explained.

Comment: Glad we agree. Thanks for your help.